# Error handler for HomeKit app

Tags: error-handling, swift

I have this universal error handler for my HomeKit app (currently in development). It grew out of wanting a single place to write error messages, show alerts, etc. I wanted a short, simple way to call it from anywhere that may generate an error.

Here's the class:

```
import UIKit
import HomeKit

class ESErrorHandler : NSObject
{
    class func handleError(error: NSError) -> Bool
    {
        NSLog("Handling error \(error) in centralized handler")

        let code = HMErrorCode(rawValue: error.code)

        switch code! {
        case HMErrorCode.FireDateInPast:
            showAlertWithTitle("Invalid date", body: "Date must be in the future")
        case HMErrorCode.AccessDenied:
            showAlertWithTitle("Access Denied", body: "You don't have permission to access the specified item")
        ... // A bunch more cases

        default:
            NSLog("Couldn't handle error with code \(error.code)")
            showAlertWithTitle("Error", body: "Couldn't successfully complete action")
            return false
        }

        return true
    }
    class func showAlertWithTitle(title: NSString, body: NSString)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
        {
            let alert = UIAlertView(title: title, message: body, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
            alert.show()
        }
    }
}
```

I call it from other code like this:

```
homeManager.addHomeWithName(currentHouseName) {(home: HMHome!, error: NSError!) in
        if error != nil
        {
            ESErrorHandler.handleError(error)

            self.title = "Add Home"
        }
        else
        {
           ... //Stuff worked, do other stuff
        }
    }
```

My concerns:

- Something feels wrong about putting using a class method for `showAlertWithTitle:body:`
- I don't really like having using `switch code!`, it seems clumsy like I'm missing something in unwrapping

Answer (score 4):

> I don't really like having using `switch code!`, it seems clumsy like
>   I'm missing something in unwrapping.

Yes, that will crash if the function is called with an error code
that does not correspond to one of the `HMErrorCode` enumeration values.
Better use *optional binding* with `if let ...`:

```
class func handleError(error: NSError) -> Bool
{
    if let code = HMErrorCode(rawValue: error.code) {
        switch code {
        case HMErrorCode.FireDateInPast:
            showAlertWithTitle("Invalid date", body: "Date must be in the future")
        case HMErrorCode.AccessDenied:
            showAlertWithTitle("Access Denied", body: "You don't have permission to access the specified item")
        // Other cases ...
        default:
            NSLog("Couldn't handle error with code \(error.code)")
            showAlertWithTitle("Error", body: "Couldn't successfully complete action")
            return false
        }
    } else {
        NSLog("Unknown error with code \(error.code)")
        showAlertWithTitle("Error", body: "Unknown error \(error.code)")
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

It is also not obvious from your code why the function has a (boolean) return
value, as the caller ignores it.

Comment: The boolean return value is so that other code could tell if the error was successfully handled. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a cleaner implementation could work as follows.

1. Create individual error notification types as strings, ie:

   `let HMErrorAccessDenied = "HMErrorAccessDenied";`
2. [Register a common handler](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/addObserver:selector:name:object:) for all of your various error notification types in your application delegate.

   `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"universalErrorHandler:", name:HMErrorAccessDenied, object:nil);`
3. Instead of tightly coupling your methods with an error handler (like your call to `ESErrorHandler.handleError(error)` in `homeManager.addHomeWithName()`) you [emit error notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/postNotificationName:object:) via `NSNotificationCenter.postNotification()` and let the registered error handler take care of reacting. This leaves your code flexible in that adding additional handlers at a later date is very easy.
4. Use the [localization features of the Apple-provided frameworks](http://rshankar.com/internationalization-and-localization-of-apps-in-xcode-6-and-swift/) in your handler to load error strings and display those in reaction to the error notifications.

This all assumes that the errors you'll be posting notifications about are **things that the user needs to be aware of** in some way (though a dialog or an update in the user interface). *Other error types*, such as recoverable errors, should be passed back to the calling code as either **return values** or **inout parameters**.